# Ajax pages - google SEO

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, seo

I build website with all pages in ajax.
The problem is the ajax pages havn't header and footer like index page.

So I want google will index the ajax pages after they inserted to index.
In other words, I want google to index my ajax pages with header and footer.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have online example, so we can check how you actually used ajax to display pages and what is the affect on URL

Answer (score 0):

You can follow googles instructions on this page: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/
This solutions work by making an image of you website specific for Googles searchengine.

Alternatively you could make a mirrorsite available for browsers without JavaScript enabled, which Google easily will index.

Comment: Google's Ajax crawling technique is obsolete. It was created as a reaction to [hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) which were superseded by `pushState` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have regular, complete webpages (you can generate them on the server) at the URLs you want the browser to display and link to them as normal
2. Provide an web api that JavaScript can get the content for a page from
3. Have your JavaScript:

   1. Bind event handlers to the links
   2. Map the URL in the href attribute of the clicked link onto the web api
   3. Use Ajax to fetch the data from the web api (as mentioned in step 2)
   4. Update the page with that data
   5. Change the URL to the actual page (as mentioned in step 1) using `pushState`

Comment: Thanks! If I install adress jquery plugin, Google will get the ajax content as I want?